# Should each DNN module live in its own web application project

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

As we're making our initial move into DNN and setting up projects, I need clarification on the Web Application Project model for creating DNN modules.

Should/can all modules live inside one web application project? Or, should each module be its own WAP?

What would best practices dictate for the project structure in the solution containing DNN modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it either way.  I've heard people do it both ways.

1. Do your modules depend on each other at all? If so, you might want to keep them all in the same project so if one gets built, they all do.
2. If not, I like to keep each module in a separate project just from a separation standpoint.  Each module/project will be smaller and easier to manage.  Just build the project and it will give you the install file.

It's just a personal preference.  I know a lot of people create one solution, then keep a separate project for each module.

Comment: #2 is the way I choose to do all my development, and the way my VS Templates are configured for. After years of doing DNN development, it is by far the cleanest and easiest to manage, especially if you have multiple developers